# Angularjs custom validation is not working using expressions

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am using below code to validate my Quantity text box. when i enter wrong number it's showing error message, but the form is submitting.

```
<span ng-show="model.Item.Quantity - model.Quantity < 0">Entered Quantity cannot be greater than the item quantity.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following way :

```
<form name="formName">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="{{itemQuantity}}" name="inputName" ng-model="propertyName" />
    <span ng-show="formName.inputName.$invalid">Error Message </span>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="formName.$invalid" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You can find more info here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[number]

Comment: Hi Philippe, i accept your answer but i have different scenario, i have edited my question now please check, how to validate this?

Comment: @RajeshGK You can interpolate inside the attributes.

Comment: this means to add custom directive to validate?

Comment: @RajeshGK this : max="{{itemQuantity}}"

Comment: @Philippe here there is no min and max scenario but we have to validate against Original quantity. **ie Entered Quantity cannot be greater than the item quantity.** here {{itemQuantity}} is original quantity.

Comment: "Entered Quantity cannot be greater than the item quantity" means that the max value  for Entered Quantity is item  quantity.